# Preparing for a fight in Osaka (dialectal んやったなぁ)

Tags: colloquial-language, kansai-ben

Subject: ironic story; place: Osaka; time: pre-mordern; situation: a boy is threatened with a sword-fight. More threatened than really called for a duel, so he has time.

The hero of the story says to himself:

> こんな事になるんやったら何か得物を持って来るんやったなぁ。

And starts to search through his belongings for something to use as a weapon.

---

The situation is clear and the meaning is easy to deduce or at least I can imagine what I would say in such a situation...

...except for the latter んやったなぁ. Either it leads to the next scene (searching the belongings):

> <sup>1</sup> Gee, things turned bad... I wonder do I have anything for a weapon...

or is just a statement of resignation:

> <sup>2</sup> Now that things turned that way, I should have brought some weapon with me...

that can be said before running away (as well as before searching for a weapon).

How shall I interpret 持って来るんやったなぁ here (as <sup>1</sup> or <sup>2</sup> or maybe something else)?

Comment: In 標準語 it would be: こんな事になるん**だ**ったら何か得物を持って来るん**だ**ったなぁ。

Comment: @choco Is it really? Let's say こんなもんやったらなぁ斬る事もでけへん is an equivalent of こんな物で斬ることもできない, but would someone say "in hyōjungo" こんなもんだったらなぁで斬ることもできない?

Comment: Hmmm... maybe...? Still (because at first I assumed it was a verb やる and your comment proved otherwise) I have no clue if and how it connected to the next scene (even as だったなぁ)...

Comment: You mean "こんなもんだったらなぁ斬ることもできない"? That's definitely possible. But なぁ is also dialectal, so it might not be "pure" hyojungo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ~のだった

means "should have", and んやった is just a colloquial dialectal form of that. So pretty much your number 2.